# Ubuntu won't recognize bootable USB or CD

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2, usb

I have gotten this **Asus N73J** and removed the Windows OS from it and installed Ubuntu on it. 
After some time, for a couple of reasons, I wanted to create Dualboot with Windows 7 along with Ubuntu, but my problem is:

**CD / DVD:**

Whenever I put the install DVD of either Windows 7 or Windows 8, it won't show up on the desktop, when I'm on Ubuntu. It should show an icon or at least show up at the "Hard disks" program.

Also, whenever I try to boot the CD from the boot menu, it either tells me to put a CD in or just shows a blinking white "_" on the top left corner without anything happening. When I take out the cd and then put it back, it still stays the same.

**USB-STICK**

I took the .iso file and tried to create a bootable USB-stick, either using terminal and the "Create bootable media" program, which is pre-installed on Ubuntu and made one successfully. But whenever I try to boot the USB then, it still has the same problem of not booting it when I choose to boot the stick.
But when I boot the USB-Stick for Ubuntu, it works fine and I can re-install Ubuntu any time.

*I've read some threads on the net but haven't found anything similar to this problem and was wondering, if the laptop is blocking these from installing and how to fix it.*

There was something like "enable CSM on the boot menu", but there is no such option, I've already looked through a couple times.

Comment: Have you verified that the Windows 7 iso image you downloaded and used for creating the DVD/USB drive are valid by comparing hash sums? Maybe there was some data corruption during the download and the image is broken. Anyway, your described problem seems not to be Ubuntu's fault, as it is not involved when your UEFI system looks for bootable removable devices. Maybe you should better move your question to [su] for that reason, where they are more specialized on Windows problems, which are off-topic here anyway. Thanks and welcome to the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: *Have you verified that the Windows 7 iso image you downloaded and used for creating the DVD/USB drive are valid by comparing hash sums? Maybe there was some data corruption during the download and the image is broken.*

I've legally purchased it and used the CD before on another PC, and it worked fine.

I asked the question in here, because it seems like Ubuntu won't recognize those 2 CD's. I've tried to put game CD's, which usually run on Windows and it recognized those, so I wanted to know if that is a bug or something.

Comment: *Maybe you should better move your question to Super User for that reason, where they are more specialized on Windows problems, which are off-topic here anyway*

Alright, could you please tell me how to move the question? It's my first time using this website, so.. ^^

Comment: AFAIK it is advised to install Win first before Ubuntu...

Comment: Yea but even if I want to, it won't recognize anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu won't recognize bootable USB or CD](https://superuser.com/questions/1190245/ubuntu-wont-recognize-bootable-usb-or-cd)

Comment: User double posted same question in multiple communities. Voting to close.